# Difference between SMPP+ and SMPP

Tags: smpp

What is the difference between smpp+ and smpp. What I understood is that SMPP+ is SMPP + Some prepaid API. But I want to know is what all are the difference in PDUs and what all additional features are there. Googling didn't give me a document worth understanding ....

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as SMPP+. In real life situations there are only SMPP versions 3.3, 3.4 and 5.0; of them 3.4 being the most common by far.

The SMPP+ you mention might be some proprietary extension of SMPP by an operator or SMS gateway but there is no standard for SMPP+.

Answer (score 3):

The SMPP+ is a proprietary version of SMPP used for USSD services. Therefore it contains some USSD-specific optional parameters, while other values of some mandatory parameters are used for USSD.

Optional parameters used for USSD in SMPP+ submit_sm:

- ussd_service_op
- ussd_session_id
- language_indicator

Optional parameters used for USSD in SMPP+ deliver_sm:

- ussd_service_op
- ussd_session_id
- language_indicator
- imsi
- hlr_address_ton
- hlr_address_npi
- hlr_address
- vlr_number_ton
- vlr_number_npi
- vlr_number_addr

Answer (score 0):

The SMPP+ term is mostly used by telecommunication solution providers to highlight that they extended the standard protocol by introducing optional TLVs to fulfill required functionality through SMPP API. USSD, SMS and LBS gateways mostly used those special TLVs for several reasons :

- To present USSD session direction; Mobile originated or terminated.
- To differentiate continuous USSD session as menu and push-pull requests(e.g. like balance query)
- To track different USSD sessions as USSD session Id
- Prioritization between SMS submission from ESME applications
- Querying current cell id of MSISDN through LBS gateway
- Retrieving serving MSC and HLR addresses.